# Which Japanese fonts are aesthetically pleasing to you?

Tags: discussion

I understand that this question is highly subjective, but I find that I have a few 'go-to' Japanese fonts which I really like the look of. I find others horrible to look at (Mincho fonts in particular). So I was wondering if there are some types of fonts which people seem to prefer aesthetically.

My current favorites are **Yu Gothic Light** and **HG Kyokasho** (see below).

> [image: Fonts]

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [chat]…

Comment: It's certainly suitable for chat, but I wouldn't mind leaving it as a question, because the various suggestions can be voted on and it's easier to refer back to them if they're left here.

Comment: You don't like *Mincho* fonts? Are you serious? :) I think [genryu](https://github.com/ButTaiwan/genryu-font) looks amazing, feels like I'm reading something right out of the Kangxi dictionary.

Comment: I'll admit that one isn't so bad, but in general I find Mincho fonts somehow irritating.

Comment: Many fancy fonts make busy kanji illegible unless displayed huge.

Answer (score 2):

I must say, I never expected to find something like this:

[image]

Japanese seal script font with *kana*! This will be my new favourite aesthetic for a long time.

Link: http://www.hakusyu.com/download_shiki_winter.php

Unfortunately, the list of characters is restricted:

> <sub>、。々〇ー０１２３４５６７８９ぁあぃいぅうぇえぉおかがきぎくぐけげこごさざしじすずせぜそぞただちぢっつづてでとどなにぬねのはばぱひびぴふぶぷへべぺほぼぽまみむめもゃやゅゆょよらりるれろゎわゐゑをんァアィイゥウェエォオカガキギクグケゲコゴサザシジスズセゼソゾタダチヂッツヅテデトドナニヌネノハバパヒビピフブプヘベペホボポマミムメモャヤュユョヨラリルレロヮワヰヱヲンヴヵヶ</sub>
>
> 愛亥一引卯丑雲影栄永益援何嘉家歌花賀海皆格楽感願希祈貴輝宜誼旧牛共恭極謹九慶敬景迎健献元虎顧五午御交光厚幸康今沙歳際昨三四子指支賜事次七社謝寿十春尚昌松祥上情色心新深申世成正清素層相足卒尊多汰第辰旦致竹中長頂鳥程展努頭導寅酉難二如年馬倍八発繁飛舞風福平別偏変鞭方望本満未巳無命明有預様用羊立竜龍力礼六和話詫壽戌撻樂禧聲萬頌

Comment: Now that is something special for sure!

Comment: Nice helpful answer & link, nice font. Thank you